# Bottom Navigation Overlapping TextView in Android Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

[image]

I have used BottomNavigationView in my app, but the text of menu item overlaps on menu icon in small devices as shown in below screenshot.

I tried this:`<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>`
but still in all Tablets its overlaps

my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_50sdp" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/bottomnavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorbottomnavigation"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottomsheetcolor"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottomsheetcolor"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

here is menu.xml file :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="HOME" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_prepwork"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
    android:title="PREP WORK" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_timetable"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    android:title="TIME TABLE" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_exam"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exambottom"
    android:title="ATTENDANCE" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_24"
    android:title="MORE" />
```

Comment: can you please add your menu? I tried with your code but its not overriding text

Comment: Just set `BottomNavigationView` height to `wrap_content`

Comment: @pratikvekariya added

Comment: @javadroid I tried but its not Working

Comment: can you remove style from navigation menu and set margin in above framlayout same height which you gave in navigation menu

Comment: @pratikvekariya its not Working

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_60sdp" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@color/white"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_video"
        android:title="Video" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_not_working"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_alert"
        android:title="Alert" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/audio"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audio"
        android:title="audio" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/chevron_left_black_36dp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_36dp"
        android:title="chevron_left_black_36dp" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_black"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
        android:title="delete_black" />

</menu>
```

Create tablet variation from

[image]

See screenshot[image]

Comment: I already mention in tablets(above 800x1280) not small device ....in small devices its woking properly thanks for answering

Comment: @aartiLadva i have updated my answer, check it. Create a tablet variation. Checked in tablet 1200x1920. Let me know if doesn't work.

Comment: please give  app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_20sdp" then check because i  have to give icon size for look bigger in tablet

Comment: with itemIconSize _20sdp it is a bit overriding, you can try with changing itemIconSize. I think you need to set bigger icon size for tablet layout

Comment: it looks too small

Comment: set bigger icon size for tablet layout